# Get image name of application using win32gui python

Tags: python, win32gui

Is there a way to get the application image name using win32gui in windows os? I can only get the windows text using win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ). I want to get the image name which you can see in taskmanager.

thanks..

Comment: Did you find a way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

```
def list_window_names():
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
```

p.s. I hope I got it right

- If it's not something I'm afraid I can't help

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Posting the first answer to an upvoted question nine years after it was asked is really rare. Respect! Please check your text formatting carefully. You can edit your posts.